# Eclipse ADT known hosts

Tags: windows, eclipse, adt, egit

I have trouble getting the official Windows ADT 21.1.0 distribution to connect to a git repository. No matter what I tried(details below) it complains about host key not present in the registry and shows me no option to accept the host key. The remote server is running Gitlab and is under my control. There's no problem with connectivity or firewalls.

What I tried so far:

1. connecting without giving a password, with user git
2. connecting while giving a password, with another user
3. adding manually the host key in the known_hosts file that is found in the ssh home directory(Preferences->General->Network Connections->SSH2->SSH2 home).

The message is always:

```
 The server's host key is not cached in the registry. You
 have no guarantee that the server is the computer you
 think it is.
 The server's rsa2 key fingerprint is:
 ssh-rsa 2048 xx:xx:xx...
 Connection abandoned.
```

RSE works without any problems, only egit gives me problems.

Answer (score 0):

You could workaround the problem by not using the ssh protocol with the git server, but instead the [git or http protocol](http://git-scm.com/book/en/Git-Internals-Transfer-Protocols).

One reason for the above message can be using a folder called "ssh" instead of ".ssh" (note the dot). Some colleague of mine experienced that, and this can easily happen when using Windows explorer, as it will silently remove the dot, when creating a folder called ".ssh". You have to use the command line instead.

Comment: I tried what you suggested, using a folder named ".ssh", and it's not it. The option of using another protocol is not always an option and I prefer to use ssh as protocol.

Comment: Sorry to hear that. Do you already have entries in your known_hosts file? If so, I would try to backup and remove the file completely to really force it to create the file new. Next thing, you could try opening a SSH connection using putty. If that works, the host would be stored by putty and egit should take it afterwards. And a third thing to look at might be the used encryption method. I'm not sure if there are any restrictions by egit or the SSH implementation used in eclipse.